# Write in specific position in file, but erasing the old content first

Tags: c++, file

I want to write something in specific position in already exists file, but I want before writing the new content, erasing the old content in this position.

For example, assume the following is the content of the target file.

```
27013.
Anderson Alston.
22.
9 Hall st.
25/7/2013.
0.      << target position here
```

Now, after modify the file content will be

```
27013.
Anderson Alston.
22.
9 Hall st.
25/7/2013.
190.    << this position has been modified
```

And finally, the following is My code that I wrote.

```
cout << "Amount of deposit: ";
cin >> amount;
ofstream ifile("file.txt", ios::out|ios::trunc);
ifile.seekp(pos); // `pos` is variable that stores the position
ifile << amount << ".";
ifile.close();
```

Comment: You realize the length of the file is changing, right? You can't easily *insert* into a text file with just the file streams (that requires *moving* all of the following data). Your best bet is to read the file in, process it, and write it back out.

Comment: @BrianNeal We can delete all of these comments if you want :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot insert data into a file in that manner.

A file is a contiguous set of bytes, and to introduce additional data into a specific region requires you to "make space" for the new content. This is achieved by allocating more space and then shifting values so that you can write to where you desire.

I would certainly not advise shifting (reading/writing) the characters in the file itself. Read the contents of the file into a char buffer, where the data can be more easily manipulated. You might consider using an array of char arrays, so you would have a char array for each line. This way you would be able to manipulate the data on a per-line basis, and write back to a file when all your modifications are complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly *insert* data in the middle of a file, just like you can't insert data into the middle of an array. You have to move everything after the point of insertion to make room for the new data.

In general, I think it's a bad idea to work with files like this. Read the file in, do whatever processing you need to, and then write the full file back out.  Also, you avoid easily corrupting the file in this way.

Comment: C/C++ doesn't have any way to erase specific line in file ? very blemish on this language.

Comment: Your lack of basic understanding of how files work is more of a blemish than C++ not having the ability to do this (inefficient) task natively.

Comment: That's fine. Then you should consider learning more about the language before you dismiss it for not having something built-in just because you think it should. Please direct me to any language that has built-in line-level file editing.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment on what about my answer was incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's hopefully an answer for you...

First, you have to know that what you have asked for in the question is only PARTIALLY possible. By this I mean that,

a. You CAN change a record of a file WITHOUT reading the whole file into the memory, BUT

b. You CANNOT insert a new record to the middle of the file without moving the other records around.

To do task 'a' above, you simple have to use a seek function to the required position and then update the record.

To do task 'b', since you're a beginner, it's best to use an array. I'm not going to write the whole code for you here. If that's what you want, you'd rather be in **my** class than in **your** C class :)

So here's a rough algorithm.

To insert a record:

```
Input data
Open the file to append. (alternatively you may seek to the end of the file)
Write the record
Close the file.
```

To EDIt a record.

```
Input a record item to search. Eg: ID or name or something unique.
Open the file (for read/write)
RecordNum = 0
found = false
While not eof and not found
  Read record
  If match found
    found= true
    display info so you can see the data
    input new fields (changes)
    seek to postion RecordNum
    Write the record to the position.
  Else
    Increment RecordNum
  End if
End while
if not found show error or something you like.
close file
```

In the methods above, you MUST use typed files. That means you must define a record structure for each record (use struct).

Answer (score -1):

You can open file like this:

```
fstream ifile("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
```